# Github - How to search a gist via API?

Tags: github, github-api, gist

I understand that it is possible to [search a repository via various criteria](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-repositories) with the Github API but how to search for a single gist or find its id?

Ideally I'd like to use `user` and `filename` but it could be a hash inside the content body:

```
https://gist.github.com/search?q=sadjghasghdhjasgdfhs
```

Comment: Specifically, what criteria would you like to use to search for a Gist?

Comment: Ideally user together with filename but it could be a string inside the content such as a md5 hash

Comment: The GitHub Search API (https://developer.github.com/v3/search/) does not currently support the ability to search for gists.

Comment: Very much wish GitHub would allow searching gists. In the meantime, it seems there are really only two options: 1) index public gists via the api and search your index; 2) perform your query with https://gist.github.com/search?q=foo and scrape the results.

Comment: p.s. anybody want to take on the task of maintaining an index of public gists and wrapping it in a simple search api? :-)

Comment: lol yes sir :) and it is also possible to search for a private gists using the scraping method via curl request

Comment: Take a look at https://github.community/t/searching-github-gists-via-api/124091/3

Answer (score 3):

I just found out that it is possible to search for a specific user and/or filename. I've looked at the advanced search of github, which uses `user:some-user-name` and `path:some-file-name`. These criteria also work on the gist search terms.

example: https://gist.github.com/search?q=user%3Amanuelvanrijn+path%3Aguid.js

Hope this helps until there's a search api available for gists

Comment: 1 for the example  until there's a search api available ;)

Comment: Any good way to loop through all the returned pages when doing it this way?

Comment: All these years later, still a sweet answer lol. Your link/example loaded in my browser and I was able to see how it looks in a UI search box too, which was really intuitive/convenient. Thanks again, from the future, and hope you guys back in 2016 have been doing well (it's nearly 2024 here)!

Answer (score 0):

The GitHub community post given in as comment as the top answer no longer works. I pulled the Ruby example from archive.org, here it is:

```
module GistSearch
  class << self
    def search_public_gists(query:, page_limit: 10)
      docs = []
      base_url = "https://gist.github.com"
      next_path = "/search?q=#{query}"

      page_limit.times do
        url = "#{base_url}#{next_path}"
        html = fetch_cached(url)

        doc = Nokogiri(html)
        docs << doc

        if !doc.search("a[rel=next]").empty?
          next_path = doc.search("a[rel=next]").attr("href").value
        else
          break
        end
      end

      docs
    end

    def build_items(queries:)
      queries.flat_map do |query|
        search_public_gists(query: query).flat_map do |doc|
          doc.
            search(".gist-snippet").
            map do |gist_snippet|
              Item.new(
                creator: gist_snippet.search(".creator a:first").text,
                title: gist_snippet.search(".creator a").map(&:text).join(" / ") + " (Matched query: #{query.inspect})",
                link: gist_snippet.search(".link-overlay").attr("href").value,
                guid: gist_snippet.search(".link-overlay").attr("href").value,
                pub_date: Time.iso8601(gist_snippet.search("time-ago").attr("datetime").value),
                content: gist_snippet.search(".js-file-line").map(&:text).join("\n"),
              )
            end
        end
      end
    end
```